# SQL How do I convert timestamp to datetime within the select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table where there are columns username, visit and timestamp.
I select user by name and visit. But the result of query must contain: username, visit, datetime.

How do I go from here:

```
select username, visit, timestamp
from Table
where username like "Jane" and visit like "cafe"
```

to the result with date?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Names are just conventions. You need to say what column types they have and what exact output you want. Additionally, don't get used to double quotes for string literals, MySQL is almost the only vendor that deviates from the standard, which is using single quotes only. It also doesn't make sense to use `like` if you don't have wildcards, as in `username like 'Jane%'`; did you mean `=`?